HTTP 500 error in a GitHub Actions pipeline of a Dockerized Laravel application
I'm starting to lose hope. I want to create a GitHub Actions pipeline to run my Laravel tests using 'php artisan test'.
My project is Dockerized and allows local code modification.
Here's my pipeline script:
name: Laravel Run Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.3'

      - name: Install PHP dependencies
        run: |
          cp .env.example .env
          cp nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf.example nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf
          sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
          sudo chmod -R 777 .
          pwd
          ls -l
          ls -a
          ls -a ./nginx/conf.d
          cat ./nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf
          composer install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader
          php artisan key:generate
          php artisan config:cache

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Install Docker Compose
        run: |
          sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.27.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          docker-compose --version

      - name: Set up Docker Compose
        run: |
          docker-compose up -d
          sleep 40
          docker-compose exec -T app php artisan migrate --force
          docker ps

      - name: Check file permissions
        run: docker-compose exec -T app ls -l /var/www

      - name: Check logs of app container
        run: docker logs laravel_app

      - name: Check logs of webserver container
        run: docker logs nginx

      - name: Run tests inside Docker container
        run: docker-compose exec -T app php artisan test

I also have the docker-compose.yml:
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: laravel_app
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - laravel
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - db
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost || exit 1" ]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 5
        restart: unless-stopped

    webserver:
        image: nginx:1.26.0-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - laravel
        restart: unless-stopped

    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: mariadb
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        networks:
            - laravel
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost -u ${DB_USERNAME} -p${DB_PASSWORD} || exit 1" ]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 5
        restart: unless-stopped

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            -   "8082:80"
        depends_on:
            -   db
        networks:
            -   laravel
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    laravel:

volumes:
    dbdata:

The Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.3.7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    zip \
    nodejs \
    netcat-openbsd

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . /var/www

RUN composer install --no-interaction --no-plugins --no-scripts
RUN npm i

COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/init.sh

CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/init.sh"]

And the init.sh file:
#!/bin/sh

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

until nc -z -v -w30 db 3306; do
  echo 'Waiting for database connection...'
  sleep 1
done

php artisan migrate

exec php-fpm

Currently, my .env and laravel.conf files are exact copies of the example files.
On my local machine, I can run tests and pass them with the command:
docker-compose exec -T app php artisan test
But in my GitHub Action, I'm getting a 500 error on a test that expects only a 200 response.
I've made a lot of changes, consulting documentation and even using AI.
Many instructions in my pipeline script are part of my research efforts.
I'm a novice, so I'm probably missing something, but I'm out of ideas.
I'm new to this platform and I'm not sure if it's appropriate to share the link to my repository, but here it is: https://github.com/Green-Blind/PhoenixPedia
I've tried several times to modify the script of my GitHub Actions pipeline.
Firstly, I tried using services instead of my docker-compose setup.
Then, I ensured that the .env.example and laravel.conf.example files were correctly copied to .env and laravel.conf.
I used 'cat' to verify the information that was present.
I modified the script to display container logs and also experimented with file read and write permissions.
I tried using the same version of docker-compose as on my computer.
I also attempted to force migration in case it hadn't been applied properly.
I added various pauses to ensure that my init.sh file could finish.
I'm really stuck on this issue.

Good news! Issue resolved.
It was something really simple...
PHP extensions were not enabled.
I spent a lot of time testing many things before realizing this major oversight.
Here's a version that works:
name: Run Laravel Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]

jobs:
  run-laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Update and Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
          sudo apt-get install -y unzip netcat-openbsd

      - name: Setup PHP Environment
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.3'
          extensions: bcmath, bz2, calendar, ctype, curl, exif, ffi, fileinfo, ftp, gettext, iconv, intl, mbstring, opcache, pdo, pdo_mysql, phar, posix, readline, shmop, sockets, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm, tokenizer

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '20'

      - name: Copy Environment Files
        run: |
          cp .env.example .env
          cp nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf.example nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf

      - name: Install PHP/Laravel and Node.js Dependencies
        run: |
          composer install --no-interaction --no-plugins --no-scripts
          npm install
          php artisan key:generate

      - name: Start Docker Compose Services
        run: |
          docker-compose up -d

      - name: Check Docker Services Status
        run: docker-compose ps

      - name: Wait for Site to be Ready
        run: |
          SITE_URL="http://localhost:8081"
          MAX_TRIES=10
          TRIES=0
          while [ $TRIES -lt $MAX_TRIES ]; do
            RESPONSE=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null $SITE_URL)
            if [ $RESPONSE -eq 200 ]; then
              echo "Site is up!"
              break
            fi
            echo "Waiting for the site to be up... ($TRIES/$MAX_TRIES)"
            TRIES=$((TRIES + 1))
            sleep 15
          done
          if [ $TRIES -eq $MAX_TRIES ]; then
            echo "Site did not become ready in time."
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Run Laravel Tests
        run: docker-compose exec -T app php artisan test

      - name: Collect Docker Logs on Failure
        if: failure()
        run: docker-compose logs --no-log-prefix app webserver db phpmyadmin


